# How can I pass the arguments from a Visual Studio Code task.json to a g++ command when the command includes a space

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I have a `Visual Studio Code` `tasks.json` file to run a `C++` file via `g++`:

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "echo",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "g++",
        "args": [
            "-I ~/vcpkg/installed/x64-osx/include/",
            "test.cpp"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        }
    }
]
}
```

The problem is the resulting command `> Executing task: g++ '-I ~/vcpkg/installed/x64-osx/include/' test.cpp <` has single quotes so that won't work.

I took a look [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) and tried this:

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "echo",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "g++",
        "args": [
            {
              "value": "-I ~/vcpkg/installed/x64-osx/include/",
              "quoting": "escape"
            },
            "test.cpp"
          ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        }
    }
]
}
```

The problem is the resulting command`> Executing task: g++ -I\ ~/vcpkg/installed/x64-osx/include/ test.cpp <` uses `escape` so has a `\`.

How can I generate the desired command:

`g++ -I ~/vcpkg/installed/x64-osx/include/ test.cpp`

Answer (score 0):

The single quotes are added because there is a space in the argument. Just make "-I" and "~/vcpkg/installed/x64-osx/include/" separate args.

```
"args": [
    "-I", "~/vcpkg/installed/x64-osx/include/",
    "test.cpp"
]
```